# What does "meta" mean for this kind of forum?

Tags: discussion, meta

I do not know if it should be asked here, but I've always wondered what "meta" means for this forum. Why not "para" from "paranormal", for example?

I participate on a lot of StackExchange (SE) forums and I saw some Meta forums associated with them.

My question is just about the significance of the term "meta" for these associated forums.

Is it about the transcendence of subjects of questions made on Meta forums in relation to normal forums? Is the subject beyond the scope of subjects from normal forum? So is it like "hiper"?

Comment: Considering that that question is about the "meta" therm, I think is not a duplicate of "What is the difference between meta sites and main sites?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, avoid referring to Stack Exchange as a "forum". It's a collection of Question + Answer sites. You ask a question, other people give you answers. Traditional internet forums are: You post something and then there can be a long discussion about that, which might lead to a discussion about something else, and so on.

The dictionary says about the word *Meta:*

> referring to itself or to the conventions of its genre; self-referential.

So it's a question + answer site *about* the question + answer sites.

Comment: Noteworthy that there was a link to _What is Meta_ given in the help menu (at any meta site), which has seemingly been a victim of the new navbar style :-(.

Comment: @user0042 https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: @gnat THX. Hard to find nowadays. I didn't expect that in the _Our Model_ section.